# Notification backup?

Tags: notifications

How can I export my push notifications so they can be imported again on accidental deletion?

If I accidentally wipe out a notification or press the clear button, Android does not ask me for confirmation and just cleans up.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use any third party app, that can read every Notification on your phone then there is a built-in Notification log in Android.
How to enable:
You can see your **Notification log** under **Settings shortcut widget**.
Long press on home screen.
Select **Add widgets"** and select **Settings**.

[image: screen shot- Settings shortcut]
Click on **Notification log** and a shortcut will appear on your home screen to launch **Notification log**.
That's it. Check details of every notification you missed.
*You can't send them back into Notification tray.*

Comment: I don't seem to have this on my Galaxy s5. What phone do you have?

Comment: I am running stock Android 7.1.1(Moto G4 Play)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an app that saves your notification history. Even after you clear your notification, you'll be able to go back and see what it was. The app is called [notification history](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree)